# Created report works in iReport but not server

Tags: jasper-reports, expression, field

I have a report with expression which works with EnglishNumberToWords.jar . This .jar convert number to words and work perfect in iReport but give error when I executing it as web app.
Report without this 
What I doing wrong?
This code of text Field expression:

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[EnglishNumberToWords.convert( $F{ODEMELER_MEBLEG}.intValue() )+" manat "+$F{QEPIQ}+" qpiq"]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Here is error:

```
    Error occured while displaying report net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : Source text : EnglishNumberToWords.convert( $F{ODEMELER_MEBLEG}.intValue() )+" manat "+$F{QEPIQ}+" qpiq"
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:203)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:591)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:559)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.evaluateExpression(JRFillElement.java:966)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluateText(JRFillTextField.java:456)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluate(JRFillTextField.java:440)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:259)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:455)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2044)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:778)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:288)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:151)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:822)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:61)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:407)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runToPdfStream(JasperRunManager.java:201)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(JasperRunManager.java:720)
co.gerger.bdf.view.JasperReportsServlet.doGet(JasperReportsServlet.java:106)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
co.gerger.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: [This may help](https://github.com/nitincool4urchat/jasper-java-examples/) you can create an issue if any of the examples is not working. Most of them are straight netbeans projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked if the iReport and Server versions are compatible?

Also, have you added this jar on the server side as well?

Comment: I added this jar file to classpath in ireport, how to add on server side?
Vesions of what? Sorry I cant understand.

Comment: After add jar file on server side problem was solved. Thanks.

Comment: What I meant was the versions of iReport and Server. I updated my answer with the clarification.